# Update post meta - check if value is same as before

Tags: wordpress

I'm updating a post meta field and that's working for me with the code below. Now I want to upgrade the code to check if new value is same as old value

```
add_action( 'updated_post_meta', 'update_function', 10, 4 );
function update_function( $meta_id, $post_id, $meta_key, $meta_value )
{
    // check if $old_value == $new_value
}
```

Should I be using some other action hook? Where is the old value saved and where the new one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the post meta value you should use get_post_meta($post_id,'meta_key',true)
Read more about it here [get_post_meta from WordPress docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/)

Then using this code inside of your function should solve your problem

```
// not sure if you should use this action hook, maybe try a different trigger
// if u=you are updating user meta then use user_register hook to update user after 
registration

// hook that you are using is update_post_meta and not updated_post_meta
add_action( 'updated_post_meta', 'update_function', 10, 4 );
function update_function( $meta_id, $post_id, $meta_key, $meta_value )
{
  // get post meta value
  $old_value = get_post_meta($post_id, $meta_key, true);
  if($old_value == $new_value){
    return false;
  }else{
    return $new_value = update_post_meta($post_id, $meta_key, $updated_value);
  }
}
```

Comment: Where does $new_value come from?

Comment: $new_value in this case is not defined previously in this example. This can be whatever you need it to be. String, object whatever you are working with. Point here is to show how to retrieve old value and update with the $new_value.